# Shortest amount of consecutive 1's in a column in C

Tags: c

I'm learning C language and I'm stuck doing this exercise and I don't know really how to solve it:

- Having a 1's and 0's matrix, find the shortest amount of consecutive 1's in any column.

An example

```
1 0 1 1 
1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

In this case the shortest amount is 2 consecutive 1 in the left column.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int i, j;
    int a[100][100];
    int minimum=999999;
    int columns,rows;

    printf("Number of Rows:");
    scanf("%i",&rows);

    printf("Number of Columns:");
    scanf("%i",&columns);

    for (i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<columns;j++) {
            scanf("%i",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (j=0;j<columns;j++) {
        int count_1s=0;

        for (i=0;i<rows;i++) {
            if (a[i][j]==1) {
                count_1s++;
            }   
            else {
                count_1s=0;
            }
        }

        if(count_1s>0&&count_1s<minimum) {
            minimum=count_1s;
        }
        printf("%i ",count_1s);
    }
    printf("%i\n",minimum);
}
```

Comment: What dictates a column?

Comment: It would probably make sense to preserve an `int last = a[i][j];` so you can compare `if (last && a[i][j])` then increment consecutive count, else, reset `last = 0;`

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: If there are two consecutive zeros, does it count that there are zero ones between them?

Comment: This statement: `if(count_1s>0&&count_1s<minimum)...` appears **after** this loop: `for (i=0;i<rows;i++)...` has completed, which means it can only update the minimum after the entire column has been processed. So it will miss a shorter sequence of 1s earlier in the column. You need to redesign your code so that after the end of **each** sequence of 1s, the code tests whether it was a shorter sequence than previously seen and, if so, update its record of the minimum seen so far. So you need to do that when a sequence of 1s ends with a zero or ends at a column end.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to can do this, but each requires knowing whether the last value in the column for the row above was a `1` or `0`. You can save a `int last = a[i][j];` value at the end of your loop (initialized to `a[0][j]` at the beginning), or simply use `a[i][j-1]`. In each case your ***inner loop*** over rows runs from `i = 1; i < rows` instead of `i = 0`.

A simple implementation of your loop calculating your shortest column count would be similar to:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        int count_1s = a[0][j];             /* initialize count to 1st val */

        for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {    /* loop from rows = 1 */
            if (!a[i][j-1])                 /* if last zero */
                count_1s = a[i][j];         /* set count to current */
            if (a[i][j])                    /* if current is one */
                count_1s++;                 /* increment each iteration */
        }

        if (count_1s < mincols)             /* update mincols */
            mincols = count_1s;

        printf ("%d ", count_1s);           /* output col count */
    }
```

Another problem that invites *Undefined Behavior* is your failure to ***validate*** the return of `scanf`. You cannot properly use any of the `scanf` family of functions (or any input function for that matter) without ***checking the return***. Otherwise you have no way to respond to a *matching-failure* or *input-failure* or the user canceling input by generating a manual `EOF` (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows). All that is needed is to ensure the input and conversion succeeded. Example:

```
    printf ("Number of Rows: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &rows) != 1 || rows > 100) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer - rows.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

(**note:** how you also need to protect your array bounds to ensure the user does not enter more rows or columns than your array can hold)

and for your `1` and `0` read, you can use:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {        /* loop reading input */
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (scanf ("%d", &a[i][j]) != 1) {
                fputs ("error: invalid integer - a[i][j].\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (void) {

    int a[100][100],
        rows, cols,
        mincols = INT_MAX;

    printf ("Number of Rows: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &rows) != 1 || rows > 100) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer - rows.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Number of Cols: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &cols) != 1 || cols > 100) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer - cols.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {        /* loop reading input */
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (scanf ("%d", &a[i][j]) != 1) {
                fputs ("error: invalid integer - a[i][j].\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)          /* (added formatting) */
        printf (i ? "--" : "-");
    putchar ('\n');

    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        int count_1s = a[0][j];             /* initialize count to 1st val */

        for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {    /* loop from rows = 1 */
            if (!a[i][j-1])                 /* if last zero */
                count_1s = a[i][j];         /* set count to current */
            if (a[i][j])                    /* if current is one */
                count_1s++;                 /* increment each iteration */
        }

        if (count_1s < mincols)             /* update mincols */
            mincols = count_1s;

        printf ("%d ", count_1s);           /* output col count */
    }
    printf ("\n\nminimum column sequence of 1's: %d\n", mincols);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using your input data (and after adding the line between the data and the individual column counts), you would get:

```
$ ./bin/mincols
Number of Rows: 5
Number of Cols: 4
1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
-------
2 4 5 5

minimum column sequence of 1's: 2
```

This is not the only way to do this, but most approaches will be similar. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.